# Align labels in cell along top (valign and vertical-align not working)

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems getting span elements within a cell to align with the top of the cell. They keep aligning in the center. I have tried `valign` as well as `vertical-align` (in the CSS).

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <span class="label label-default"> Test </span>
                <span class="label label-default"> Test </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="label label-default"> Test </span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td> 
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit:

The only relevant CSS is the following:

```
.label-cal {
    background-color: #5d97ce;
    display:block;
    margin:.3em;
  padding: .3em;
 }
```

The table class is part of bootstrap

[image: Note how single span aligns center]

Comment: Can you please also paste the CSS to go along with the HTML or perhaps a JSFiddle?

Comment: did u tried a valign="top"?

Comment: Edited to include CSS details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works like a charm. With bootstrap make sure to be more specific with the css-classes. Use `.table td` instead of `td`.

```css
.table span {
  display: block;
}
.table td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <span class="label label-default"> Test </span>
                <span class="label label-default"> Test </span>
            </td>

            <td>
                <span class="label label-default"> Test </span>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td> 
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not working for me. Currently checking to see if Bootstrap is overriding something...

Comment: alternatively use `table.table td` instead of `td` only.

Comment: Yep, that's what just worked for me! using .table>tbody>tr>td. I'll accept your answer, but maybe update the css code you posted?

Comment: Nice! I will update the answer, and add the bootstrap framework.